# ASP.NET MVC 3 Json Model Binding with 3 levels object

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Why doesnt 3 level nesting model binding from json work?

Testing with 2 levels, say adding a string property on LevelTwo, works, but 3 levels doesnt? Is this by design, a bug, or am I missing something?

Client side jQuery post:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "MyController/MyAction",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            Level1: {
                Level2: {
                    StringValue: "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Server side model:

```
public class MyForm
{
    public LevelOne Level1 { get; set; }
}

public class LevelOne
{
    public LevelTwo Level2 { get; set; }
}

public class LevelTwo
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesnt 3 level nesting model binding from json work

You are not sending any JSON to the server. If you want to send a JSON request here's how:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "MyController/MyAction",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
        Level1: { 
            Level2: { 
                StringValue: "Test" 
            } 
        } 
    })
});
```

The `JSON.stringify` method is what serializes the javascript literal into a JSON string. It is natively built in modern browsers. If you need to support legacy browsers you could include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

Comment: Doh! Thanks! I assumed that dataType: "json" was all that was needed. You know, assumptions is the mother of all...

Comment: @MatteS, `dataType: 'json'` indicates the response content type, not the request. Also if your server sends proper Content-Type response header to application/json you don't even need it as jQuery will automatically infer it. You can omit this parameter from your ajax request.

Comment: Yes. This made me go back and recall why the dataType option was added to begin with in our code base, and it might be worth noting that it adds the header "Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*;" to the request, and thats something our error handling logic likes.